# EF Core Power Tools generate models in a different project

Tags: c#, .net, ef-power-tools

I'm working with a gigantic database and have my Entities in a project of its own, separate from the DB Project. EF Core Power Tools gives the option of naming the place where your models will be added to once generated, is there any way that it could generate models in another project?

Answer: This is as simple as adding ../[project_name]/[folder_name]
to the text box that asks where you want the models to be generated

Comment: Well if it lets you specify the path, can't you tell it to use a path inside the other project?

Comment: OK, what am I doing wrong? I'm using the same style path that you suggest but I get the model classes in the separate project with these linked files in the contexts project. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?